# Entanglement of formation for two qutrits

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

For a pure bipartite state $|\psi\rangle\in\mathbb C^d\otimes \mathbb C^d$, the [entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_entanglement) is given by $E(|\psi\rangle) = S(\mathrm{tr}_B|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)$, with $S(\rho)=-\mathrm{tr}(\rho\log\rho)$ the von Neumann entropy.  For an arbitrary bipartite mixed state $\rho$, the Entanglement of Formation (EoF) is defined as the minimum average entanglement of an ensemble of pure states that represents the given mixed state. For two qubits, and explicit formula for the Entanglement of Formation [is known](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9709029).

I would like to compute the Entanglement of Formation for an arbitrary mixed state of two qutrits. Are there any known results for non-trivial upper and lower bounds for the entanglement of formation of two qutrits?

Comment: I edited your question for clarity; let me know if this is ok.

Comment: Regarding the question, have you looked at SDP relexations? There are also results for special families such as isotropic states which give bounds.

Comment: I don't quite see why the (edited) version of the question has been closed as unclear what you're asking.  (This was different for the unedited one, which however only acquired two close votes IIRC.)  I think this is a very clear question, though it is not entirely clear if there is a simple answer.  (I was going to try to to write one, though.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Two qutrits... in what state? Separable? Maximally entangled? The OP is ill-posed as currently phrased.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Dude!  If it is separable, the EoF is zero.  If it is maximally entangled, the EoF is $\log 3$.  --  Seriously, I don't know what the OP meant, but if I were to ask the question, I would like to know if for an *arbitrary* (mixed) two-qutrit state, non-trivial bounds are known.  Since if I were to ask it for a more specific state, I would have specified it.  --  Do you have a suggestion what to change to make it a clear-posed question??  I"m a bit puzzled it is still acquiring downvotes.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9709029 is entitled *Entanglement of Formation of an Arbitrary State of Two Qubits* (very famous paper; the reason everyone computes the concurrence). Is this, or the abstract, unclear?

Comment: I've done some further editing.  @Bipulan: Do you care about your question (and the answer)?  Commenting from your side might help, clarify the question and encourage answers!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch that's a very different (and much better) question now.